# TEXT values in sqlite databases

Tags: sqlite, optimization

Do sqlite databases use anything like a flyweight pattern for TEXT values. If I'm repeatedly using only a few different, short TEXT values in a column, would it be better to replace them with integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite stores each copy of the text column individually:

```
$ sqlite3 pancakes.sqlt
sqlite> create table pancakes (s text);
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');
sqlite> insert into pancakes (s) values ('where is pancakes house?');

$ strings pancakes.sqlt
SQLite format 3
Itablepancakespancakes
CREATE TABLE pancakes (s text)
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
=where is pancakes house?
```

So if you want to avoid duplicating your strings you should use integers, set up a separate table to map your integers to strings, and then add a [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) to this new table so that you can ensure referential integrity.

Comment: @ajk: I gave up *foo* for *pancakes*.